# C++ How to format a text file into an html file

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am very new to C++. I have the building blocks for what I need my program to do, which is: Read a text file inputted by command line (ex. `./textToHtml.exe Alien.txt`) and create an html file from the text file by implementing the correct HTML tags when necessary.

I have provided the code below, as well as the html file structure. This is for a project and I need to have the line breaks `<br>` after each paragraph and each line blank line. I have provided the last HTML structure as what I want it to look like.

Be advised, I am sure I have some unnecessary lines or redundant code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream txtFile(argv[1]);

    std::string fn = argv[1];
    std::string fileName = fn.substr(0, fn.size() - 4);
    if (txtFile)
    {
        std::ofstream html(fileName + "1.txt");
        if (html)
        {
            html << "<HTML>\n"
                 << "<head>\n"
                 << "<title>";
            std::string line{};
            if (std::getline(txtFile, line))
            {
                html << line << "</title>" << '\n';
            }
            html << "</head>\n"
                 << "<body>\n";
            while (std::getline(txtFile, line))
            {
                html << line << "<br>" << '\n';
            }
            html << "</body>" << '\n'
                 << "</html>" << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The HTML file looks like this:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<title>Are These Aliens Martians?</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
an adaptation<br>
<br>
The men from Earth stared at the aliens.<br>
The little green men had pointed heads and<br>
orange toes with one long curly hair on each toe.<br>
<br>
H. G. Wells' novel The War of the Worlds (1898)<br>
has had an extraordinary influence on science fiction. <br>
Wells' Martians are a technologically advanced species<br>
with an ancient civilization. They somewhat resemble<br>
cephalopods, with large, bulky brown bodies and<br>
sixteen snake-like tentacles, in two groups of eight,<br>
around a quivering V-shaped mouth; they move around in<br>
100 feet tall tripod fighting-machines they assemble<br>
upon landing, killing everything in their path.<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
by your name<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

What I need the HTML file to look like:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<title>Are These Aliens Martians?</title> //my output has <br> here
<br>
<br>
an adaptation<br>
<br>
The men from Earth stared at the aliens.
The little green men had pointed heads and
orange toes with one long curly hair on each toe.<br> //Just need a <br> at the end of each paragraph
<br>
H. G. Wells' novel The War of the Worlds (1898)
has had an extraordinary influence on science fiction.
Wells' Martians are a technologically advanced species
with an ancient civilization. They somewhat resemble
cephalopods, with large, bulky brown bodies and
sixteen snake-like tentacles, in two groups of eight,
around a quivering V-shaped mouth; they move around in
100 feet tall tripod fighting-machines they assemble
upon landing, killing everything in their path.<br> //Again just one <br> here not one each line
<br>
<br>
<br>
by your name<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You never close the title tag after reading the first line, you jump straight into the loop.

Comment: @AndreMotta I need to write the first line and then print the title close tag but don't know how

Comment: FYI what you need doesn't look a valid HTML because there isn't `</head>` tag and there is a `</body>` tag without `<body>` tag.

Comment: Simply write the first line and print the title close tag before the loop: `if(std::getline(txtFile, line)) html << line << "</title>" << '\n';`

Comment: Yes these are problems I haven't listed, mb. But Like i said to Andre, if I could write just the first line of my text file which would be the title, i could then write in the </head> and then <body> tags

Comment: Also you will have to escape special characters like `<` and `>` to produce a valid HTML.

Comment: What about using the `<p>` and `</p>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void htmlencode(std::string &s)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    while ((pos = s.find_first_of("<>&", pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string replacement;
        switch (s[pos])
        {
            case '<':
                replacement = "&lt;";
                break;
            case '>':
                replacement = "&gt;";
                break;
            case '&':
                replacement = "&amp;";
                break;
        }
        s.replace(pos, 1, replacement);
        pos += replacement.size();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string fn = argv[1];

    std::ifstream txtFile(fn);
    if (txtFile)
    {
        std::string fileName = fn.substr(0, fn.rfind('.'));

        std::ofstream html(fileName + "1.html");
        if (html)
        {
            html << "<HTML>\n"
                << "<head>\n"
                << "<title>";
            std::string line;
            if (std::getline(txtFile, line))
            {
                htmlencode(line);
                html << line;
            }
            html << "</title>\n"
                << "</head>\n"
                << "<body>\n";
            bool lastLineNotEmpty = false;
            while (std::getline(txtFile, line))
            {
                if (line.empty())
                {
                    if (lastLineNotEmpty)
                        html << "<br>\n";
                    html << "<br>\n";
                    lastLineNotEmpty = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (lastLineNotEmpty)
                        html << '\n';
                    htmlencode(line);
                    html << line;
                    lastLineNotEmpty = true;
                }
            }
            if (lastLineNotEmpty)
                html << "<br>\n";
            html << "</body>\n"
                << "</html>\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/70wyKg)

However, HTML has `<p></p>` tags that are specifically designed for paragraphs, so you should consider using them instead of `<br>`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
     
void htmlencode(std::string &s)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    while ((pos = s.find_first_of("<>&", pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string replacement;
        switch (s[pos])
        {
            case '<':
                replacement = "&lt;";
                break;
            case '>':
                replacement = "&gt;";
                break;
            case '&':
                replacement = "&amp;";
                break;
        }
        s.replace(pos, 1, replacement);
        pos += replacement.size();
    }
}
     
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string fn = argv[1];

    std::ifstream txtFile(fn);
    if (txtFile)
    {
        std::string fileName = fn.substr(0, fn.rfind('.'));
     
        std::ofstream html(fileName + "1.html");
        if (html)
        {
            html << "<HTML>\n"
                << "<head>\n"
                << "<title>";
            std::string line;
            if (std::getline(txtFile, line))
            {
                htmlencode(line);
                html << line;
            }
            html << "</title>\n"
                << "</head>\n"
                << "<body>\n";
            bool inParagraph = false;
            while (std::getline(txtFile, line))
            {
                if (line.empty())
                {
                    if (inParagraph)
                    {
                        inParagraph = false;
                        html << "</p>\n";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!inParagraph)
                    {
                        inParagraph = true;
                        html << "<p>\n";
                    }
                    htmlencode(line);
                    html << line << '\n';
                }
            }
            if (inParagraph)
                html << "</p>\n";
            html << "</body>\n"
                << "</html>\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/W3cSgd)